# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GTMSessionFetcher/Core"

Tags: flutter

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GTMSessionFetcher/Core"
`

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GTMSessionFetcher/Core":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth (= 10.3.0) was resolved to 10.3.0, which depends on
        FirebaseAuth (~> 10.3.0) was resolved to 10.3.0, which depends on
          GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, >= 2.1)

    mobile_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/mobile_scanner/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning (~> 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
        MLKitBarcodeScanning (~> 2.2.0) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
```

`